# Adding element of a range of values to every N rows in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that is ordered and consecutive:

```py
    Hour  value
0      1     41
1      2      5
2      3      7
3      4    107
4      5     56
5      6     64
6      7     46
7      8     50
8      9     95
9     10     81
10    11      8
11    12     94
```

I want to add a range of values to each N rows (4 in this case), e.g.:

```py
    Hour  value  val
0      1     41    1
1      2      5    1
2      3      7    1
3      4    107    1
4      5     56    2
5      6     64    2
6      7     46    2
7      8     50    2
8      9     95    3
9     10     81    3
10    11      8    3
11    12     94    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['val'] = np.arange(len(df))//4+1
```

Output:

```
    Hour  value  val
0      1     41    1
1      2      5    1
2      3      7    1
3      4    107    1
4      5     56    2
5      6     64    2
6      7     46    2
7      8     50    2
8      9     95    3
9     10     81    3
10    11      8    3
11    12     94    3
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can create val column based from the index as follows:

```
df['val'] = 1 + df.index//4

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Hour    value  val
0   1      41      1
1   2      5       1
2   3      7       1
3   4      107     1
4   5      56      2
5   6      64      2
6   7      46      2
7   8      50      2
8   9      95      3
9   10     81      3
10  11     8       3
11  12     94      3
```